# Error message 'package had non-zero exit status'

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed R with Anaconda. Trying to execute

```
install.packages("isoband")
```

in Jupyter Notebook yields to error message

> Warning message in install.packages("isoband"): “installation of
> package ‘isoband’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of
> packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done

Does anyone have a guess what the problem might be? I am using a Macbook (M1). Thank you!

Here the whole error message:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/isoband_0.2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1671911 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘isoband’ ...
** package ‘isoband’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c clip-lines.cpp -o clip-lines.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c init.cpp -o init.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c isoband.cpp -o isoband.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c polygon.cpp -o polygon.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c separate-polygons.cpp -o separate-polygons.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c test-clip-lines.cpp -o test-clip-lines.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c test-runner.cpp -o test-runner.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c test-separate-polygons.cpp -o test-separate-polygons.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib -L/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib -o isoband.dylib clip-lines.o init.o isoband.o polygon.o separate-polygons.o test-clip-lines.o test-runner.o test-separate-polygons.o -L/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: isoband.dylib] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘isoband’
* removing ‘/Users/patrick/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_environment/lib/R/library/isoband’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘isoband’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/90/dbqm7c3s4rs4r_0fg249fgsm0000gn/T/RtmpVOx7tE/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Comment: There are usually other warnings or error messages associated with a fail like that, perhaps from a compiler or due to failed dependencies. Please include all text between `install.packages` until the next prompt. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans I've included all text, thank you!

Comment: That's *much* more informative, thank you! (Unfortunately I don't know how to resolve that issue, but now the issue is clearer.)